# Join multiple grouped dataframes by key in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I performed the operations I wanted one-by-one. They give me the result I want. So to finish I wanted to join the grouped dataframes by the same key I used to group them. Now I'm getting a "*** KeyError: 'key'" because the grouped dataframes doesn't have a "key" column that would allow me to perform the merge operation.
I'm giving my first steps on Pandas. Is there a way to keep the key column in the groupby so I can perform the merge or a easier way to achieve the same result shown in the desired output?

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {
    'key': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
    'type_op': ['OP1', 'OP2', 'OP3', 'OP2', 'OP1', 'OP3', 'OP2', None, 'OP1', 'OP3'],
    'type_xp': ['XP2', 'XP2', None, 'XP3', 'XP1', None, 'XP1', 'XP3', None, 'XP3'],
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(raw_data)

total_op1 = df[df['type_op']=='OP1'][['type_op', 'key']].groupby('key').agg(['count'])
total_op2 = df[df['type_op']=='OP2'][['type_op', 'key']].groupby('key').agg(['count'])
total_op3 = df[df['type_op']=='OP3'][['type_op', 'key']].groupby('key').agg(['count'])
total_opn = df[df['type_op'].isnull()][['type_op', 'key']].groupby('key').agg(['count'])

total_xp1 = df[df['type_xp']=='XP1'][['type_xp', 'key']].groupby('key').agg(['count'])
total_xp2 = df[df['type_xp']=='XP2'][['type_xp', 'key']].groupby('key').agg(['count'])
total_xp3 = df[df['type_xp']=='XP3'][['type_xp', 'key']].groupby('key').agg(['count'])
total_xpn = df[df['type_xp'].isnull()][['type_xp', 'key']].groupby('key').agg(['count'])

dn = df.drop_duplicates(subset='key')['key']

pd.merge(dn, total_op1, on='key', how='outer')
# ...

# the output I want...

# key   TOP1    TOP2    TOP3    TOPN    TXP1    TXP2    TXP3    TXPN    TOTAL
# a     1       1       NaN     1       NaN     2       1       NaN     6
# b     1       1       1       NaN     1       NaN     NaN     2       6
# c     1       NaN     2       NaN     1       NaN     2       1       7
# d     NaN     1       NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     1
```

Comment: You can pass param `as_index=False` to [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby)

Comment: Looks like you could also achieve the desired result by concatenating two pivots rather than 8 groupbys.  Might save a bit of work.